# Por que estas codigo no me devuelven un valor 0?

Tags: pseint, pseudocódigo

Tengo un codigo en **PSeInt** que estoy **calculado el area y el perimetro de un circulo**. A esto le agrego 2 subrutinas para realizar las funciones y que **me retorne un valor** para asi mostrarlo. Razonando, puedo entender que mi problema o inconveniente estaria en las variables de retorno, podria ser ese el caso. Pero no puede ser el inconveniente porque la sintaxis esta correcta. O podria ser que no esta sincronizada, por decirlo asi, la funcion cuando la llamo para realizar dicha operacion.

```
Funcion A <- radio_circulo(radio)
    Definir A Como real 
    
    A = numeroPI * r^2
FinFuncion 

Funcion P <- perimetro_circulo(radio)
    Definir P Como real 
    
    P = 2 * numeroPI * r
FinFuncion

Algoritmo Perimetro_Area
    Definir area, perimetro, radio Como Entero
    Definir numeroPI Como Real
    
    numeroPI = 3.1416;
    radio = 0;
    
    Escribir 'Ingrese el radio del circulo: '
    Leer radio;
    
    area = radio_circulo(radio);
    perimetro = perimetro_circulo(radio);
    Escribir "Su area es: ", area;
    Escribir "Su perimetro es: ", perimetro 
    
FinAlgoritmo
```

**Edicion del codigo sugerida en los comentarios:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**Como se puede Ver el codigo al cambiarlo me da unos que me dice que no se realacionan bien la llamada de cada una de las funciones.**

Comment: ¿Dónde está la definición de "r"?

Comment: @Peter M a "r" no lo tengo definida

Comment: ¿Qué es el "r" en "A = numeroPI * r^2"?  ¿Cómo recibe un valor?

Comment: Si. Me fije que r no estaba definido, que lo que tenia definido era radio. Ahora lo cambie y me funciono. Gracias @Peter M por señalarme ese detalle

Answer (score 1):

Hasta donde sé, tienes que darle el tipo de dato de salida a la definición del subproceso, no simplemente como una variable local.

```
Funcion Real A <- radio_circulo(radio)
    A = numeroPI * r^2
FinFuncion
```

Comment: No entiendo. Si lo hago asi, me da un error

Comment: @LuisAlejandroBatistaGalvan por favor, los intentos y aclaraciones, añádelos a la pregunta editándola, incluyendo el error completo que te da. Mi PSEInt no es bueno pero quiero ayudar ;)

Comment: Ok. Yo hice lo que me comentaste. Pero me da el siguiente error que mostrare en la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

En PseInt los SubProcesos (con o sin valor de retorno), no se puede especificar el tipo de dato, ni llamarse como un tipo de dato.
Borra la palabra clave Real

```
Funcion A <- radio_circulo(radio)
    A <- numeroPI * r^2;
FinFuncion
```